# blitting pygame.Surface() onto pygame.OPENGL display

Tags: python, pygame

How can I blit a pygame.Surface() object onto a pygame.OPENGL display and flip the display?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

RES = (640, 480)
display = pygame.display.set_mode(RES, pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.OPENGL)

bg_img = pygame.Surface(RES)
bg_img.fill((255, 255, 255))

display.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Game Dev/TESTS/Clock Comparison/opengl_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    display.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
error: Cannot blit to OPENGL Surfaces (OPENGLBLIT is ok)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you expect the normal methods of blitting and flipping not to work? If you're concerned about efficiency, calling `surface.convert` or `surface.convert_alpha` might improve things (with no arguments they make the surface have the same pixel format as the display surface).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! (_edited question_) - That's why.

Comment: (convert() / convert_alpha() does not solve the issue)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.
To avoid the error, the display surface needs to use the `pygame.OPENGLBLIT` flag instead of the `pygame.OPENGL` flag, **however** after running code like this:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

RES = (640, 480)
display = pygame.display.set_mode(RES, pygame.OPENGLBLIT)

bg_img = pygame.Surface(RES).
bg_img.fill((255, 255, 255))

display.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
input()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

the display window remains **blank**.

The pygame documentation lists this flag as:

> create an OpenGL rendering context /
>   and use it for blitting.  Obsolete.

You will need to find a way to do whatever you were trying in `pyOpenGL` itself instead.