# Draw objects on moderngl context in Pygame

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, window, python-moderngl

I wrote this simple program that displays an image onto a `moderngl` context, using `pygame`, and my goal is to draw a rectangle on the screen. (This is obviously just a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), and the real goal is to animate the texture and make more than a rectangle on the screen).

```
import moderngl
import numpy as np
import pygame
from PIL import Image


class MyPyGame:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)

        self.context = moderngl.create_context()

        image = Image.open("test.jpg").transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
        self.texture = self.context.texture(image.size, 3, image.tobytes())
        self.texture.use(0)

        self.program = self.context.program(
            vertex_shader="""
            #version 330
            in vec2 in_position;
            out vec2 uv0;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 0.0, 1.0);
                uv0 = (0.5 * in_position) + vec2(0.5);
            }
            """,
            fragment_shader="""
            #version 330
            out vec4 fragColor;
            uniform sampler2D texture0;
            in vec2 uv0;
            void main() {
                fragColor = texture(texture0, uv0);
            }
            """)

        vertices_quad_2d = np.array([-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
                                     -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)
        vertex_buffer_quad_2d = self.context.buffer(vertices_quad_2d.tobytes())
        self.vertex_array = self.context.vertex_array(self.program, [(vertex_buffer_quad_2d, "2f", "in_position")])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            self.vertex_array.render()
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyPyGame()
    app.run()
```

### Some things I tried:

1. Draw a rectangle as is the "regular" way with `pygame`, that is, add this line in the main `run` method, either before or after the vertex array rendering (both didn't work):

   ```
    pygame.draw.rect(self._surface, (200, 200, 200), [100, 100, 100, 100])
   ```
2. Instead of flag `pygame.OPENGL`, use flag `pygame.OPENGLBLIT` and then `blit` the rectangle (didn't work, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207529/blitting-pygame-surface-onto-pygame-opengl-display))
3. Use the `moderngl` context as a window inside the main display, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874411/2934048), and then `blit` the rectangle onto the main display. This is **not** what I am aiming for, I want to able to display texts and shapes onto the context, but still, wanted to at least try this. Didn't work either, the code below (replacing the corresponding code in the `__init__`) resulted in an exception `cannot detect OpenGL context`:

   ```
    pygame.init()
    self.main_window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    self.graphics_window = pygame.Surface((700, 600), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
    self.main_window.blit(self.graphics_window, (100, 0))
    self.context = moderngl.create_context()
   ```
4. Use "out of the box" window from `moderngl_window` using `pygame` ([code here](https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/blob/master/moderngl_window/context/pygame2/window.py)). Again, didn't succeed to draw a rectangle onto the context itself - tried to add the same line from (1) either inside the window code itself, or when I write my own window that inherits from this pygame window.

[Working on: Windows10, python3.6, pygame 1.9.6, moderngl 5.6.1]

How can I create a window that is both displaying graphics and has a layer of costume objects? (text, buttons, etc.)

EDIT: Perhaps a clarification for my motivation is needed: I would like to have one layer of graphics in the background, that in the example above is some manipulation of an input image. Then, in the foreground, I would like to have some costume PyGame objects like geometric shapes, buttons, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that with pygame v2.0.0.dev6 you are able to draw a rectangle on the context? Can you please explain how? Thanks! @Rabbid76

Comment: I think I've misunderstood your question. I thought the program in the question is not working. Anyway I don't think that I understand what you try to achieve. In general a OpenGL window is not "layered", but the entire scene is drawn in every frame.

Comment: I know the moderngl window itself is not "layered", which is why I am looking for another program/package/tool that will render both the moderngl context and *another* layer with the buttons, texts, etc. Is it clearer now? Thanks! @Rabbid76

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Anyway it is a bad idea to mix different tool sets. A pure OpenGL solution would mean to render the "layers" to different framebuffers and to _blit_ the frambuffers to the window.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this? I haven't found one yet and this is the goal of this question - to figure out how to to make it work... @Rabbid76

Answer (score 3):

When mixing moderngl and pygame you probably want moderngl to do all the redering to the screen. Things you render with pygame should be rendered to a separate surface. This surface is then converted to a `moderngl.Texture` so we can draw it to the screen with OpenGL.

There is even an offical example in the moderngl-window project: https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/blob/master/examples/advanced/pygame2.py

If you have questions about the pygame window initialization you can look at the pygame window backend : https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/blob/5cf117ca9c0ef8cbde772d51041a039fc611b6c7/moderngl_window/context/pygame2/window.py#L28-L65

I created a new example that renders a pygame surface to the screen. It's alpha blended on top of the current background. Anything you render in pygame needs to be rendered to this surface and it's uploaded to graphics memory every frame.

The new example is located here: https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/blob/master/examples/advanced/pygame2_simple.py

```
import math
from pathlib import Path
import pygame
import moderngl
import moderngl_window
from moderngl_window import geometry


class Pygame(moderngl_window.WindowConfig):
    """
    Example using pygame with moderngl.
    Needs to run with ``--window pygame2`` option.
    """
    title = "Pygame"
    window_size = 1280, 720
    resource_dir = (Path(__file__) / '../../resources').absolute()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if self.wnd.name != 'pygame2':
            raise RuntimeError('This example only works with --window pygame2 option')

        self.pg_res = (320, 180)
        # Create a 24bit (rgba) offscreen surface pygame can render to
        self.pg_screen = pygame.Surface(self.pg_res, flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
        # 24 bit (rgba) moderngl texture
        self.pg_texture = self.ctx.texture(self.pg_res, 4)
        self.pg_texture.filter = moderngl.NEAREST, moderngl.NEAREST

        self.texture_program = self.load_program('programs/texture.glsl')
        self.quad_fs = geometry.quad_fs()

    def render(self, time, frametime):
        self.render_pygame(time)

        self.ctx.clear(
            (math.sin(time) + 1.0) / 2,
            (math.sin(time + 2) + 1.0) / 2,
            (math.sin(time + 3) + 1.0) / 2,
        )
    
        self.ctx.enable(moderngl.BLEND)
        self.pg_texture.use()
        self.quad_fs.render(self.texture_program)
        self.ctx.disable(moderngl.BLEND)

    def render_pygame(self, time):
        """Render to offscreen surface and copy result into moderngl texture"""
        self.pg_screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))  # Make sure we clear with alpha 0!
        N = 8
        for i in range(N):
            time_offset = 6.28 / N * i
            pygame.draw.circle(
                self.pg_screen,
                ((i * 50) % 255, (i * 100) % 255, (i * 20) % 255),
                (
                    math.sin(time + time_offset) * 55 + self.pg_res[0] // 2,
                    math.cos(time + time_offset) * 55 + self.pg_res[1] // 2),
                math.sin(time) * 4 + 15,
            )

        # Get the buffer view of the Surface's pixels
        # and write this data into the texture
        texture_data = self.pg_screen.get_view('1')
        self.pg_texture.write(texture_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pygame.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I am aware of the roles of pygame and moderngl, and even linked myself in the question to the same resources you linked to. Were you able to make this integration work and create a layer of costume objects?

Comment: Ok. Let's give this another chance. What are "consume objects"? I assume you just mean two texture layers that needs to be combined somehow? If this is the case I can provide an example

Comment: As written in the question, an example would be a rectangle. And I do not wish to create this rectangle in the shaders/textures, because going forward I would like to create many many such objects, and I want a simple way to do that. Would love to see an example for this if you have :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. If this is not what you are looking for you will have to clarify what you want to achieve. The questions is already very vague.

Comment: Wow @Grimmy I really appreciate the extra mile. Thanks!. I cloned the new repo and played with your new example, and was ***still unable*** to make the background an input image instead of plain white [I tried to combine your new example with something like `geometry_cube.py`, so imagine the crate in the background, and the circles in the foreground]. I added a clarification at the end of my question, I hope my motivation is clearer now.

Comment: Updated the example again. It clears the screen with a background color and alpha blends the pygame surface on top. This is the simples way to "layer" a surface on top with transparency. You need to make sure the pygame surface as alpha channel and is cleared with 0 alpha value.

Comment: Hey @Grimmy thank you so much!! This took me most of the way to what I was looking for :) I sent a PR with the example that is the exact answer to what I was looking for - a background image and a foreground layer of objects.

Comment: @DalyaG Thank you! I appreciate the contribution.

Comment: If you need to discuss anything related to moderngl/window we do have a very friendly discord server linked in the READMEs on github. It's mostly data scientists.

Answer (score 0):

Greatly based on @Grimmy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63154114/2934048) above, here is the code that integrates `modernl-window` and `PyGame2`, it is based on some [examples](https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/tree/master/examples) from the `moderngl-window` repo:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pygame
import moderngl
import moderngl_window
from moderngl_window import geometry


class Pygame(moderngl_window.WindowConfig):
    title = "Pygame"
    window_size = 1280, 720
    resource_dir = (Path(__file__) / '../../resources').absolute()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create a 24bit (rgba) offscreen surface pygame can render to
        self.pg_screen = pygame.Surface(self.window_size, flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
        # 24 bit (rgba) moderngl texture
        self.pg_texture = self.ctx.texture(self.window_size, 4)
        self.pg_texture.filter = moderngl.NEAREST, moderngl.NEAREST

        self.texture_program = self.load_program('programs/texture.glsl')
        self.quad_texture = self.load_texture_2d('textures/python-bg.png')
        self.quad_fs = geometry.quad_fs()

    def render(self, time, frametime):
        self.ctx.clear()

        self.ctx.enable(moderngl.BLEND)

        # Render background graphics
        self.quad_texture.use()
        self.texture_program['texture0'].value = 0
        self.quad_fs.render(self.texture_program)

        # Render foreground objects
        self.pg_texture.use()
        self.render_pygame(time)
        self.quad_fs.render(self.texture_program)

        self.ctx.disable(moderngl.BLEND)

    def render_pygame(self, time):
        """Render to offscreen surface and copy result into moderngl texture"""
        self.pg_screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))  # Make sure we clear with alpha 0!
        pygame.draw.rect(self.pg_screen, (200, 200, 200), [100, 100, 100, 100])

        # Get the buffer view of the Surface's pixels
        # and write this data into the texture
        texture_data = self.pg_screen.get_view('1')
        self.pg_texture.write(texture_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    moderngl_window.run_window_config(Pygame, args=('--window', 'pygame2'))
```

- *Has been tested on Ubuntu18.04 with Python3.6*